# In Excel sheet I want to add semicolon to a cell that time format is HH MM SS

Tags: microsoft-excel

Example

09::08:00

09:09:01

I want to add semicolon like this

09::08:00;

09:09:01;

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUekt.png)

Comment: When i add semicolon to this cell 09:08:00 then it changes to 0.380555555555556; but i want semicolon in HHMMSS format only.

Comment: If the cell format is `General/Number or even Text`, then you may enter `09::08::00;` but remember Excel will never consider it as TIME! Please [Edit] your question and write the reason behind using TIME in such uncommon format,, better add Screen Shot ,, and avoid vote to close the question.

Comment: added image that changed after i tried to add semicolon in time format.(i want this for back testing purpose)

Comment: The screen shot U have added is totally different than the data you have shared with the Question !!

Comment: Hi @karthik ,, check my post I'm sure this is what you are looking for .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the format in custom format:

[image]

Also you could point to a cell with the time you want using the formula:
=HOUR(A2)&":"&MINUTE(A2)&":"& SECOND(A2)&";"

Comment: Check the Screen Shot attached with the question and your method works for a different issue,, plzz [edit] the post !

Comment: I think the screen shot is showing the error, the format wanted is in the question... which is what is achieved in the answer above. I think.

Answer (score 0):

**:Caveat:**

- *The NUMBER, MILITARY TIME or even TIME written in correct format could have TWO COLON between Hours, Minutes and Seconds, and does have SEMI COLON at end also.*
- *But Excel doesn't considers the TIME entered as you have at top with the question `09::08:00` as a TIME value, also if you apply any formula then get `#VALUE` error.*

---

*Below are methods, applies TWO COLON in between & SEMI COLON at end.*

[image]

- To convert Number or Military Time, into desire format the Formula in cell `L101` and `M101`:

  ```
  =(TIME(LEFT(K101,LEN(K101)-2),RIGHT(K101,2),0))
  ```

**N.B.** This works if & when cell has 4 digits.

- Formula in cell `L106` and `M106`:

  ```
  =(INT(K106/10000)&":"&INT(MOD(K106,10000)/100)&":"&MOD(K106,100))+0
  ```

**N.B.** This works with more than 4 digits.

- Cell format applied for SEMI COLON at end.

  `h:mm\;`
- This may be `h:mm:ss\;`
- Cell format for 2 COLON in between & SEMI COLON at end.

  `h:\:mm:ss\;`
- Cell `K110` has TIME value and cell format applied on cell `M110` is,

  `h:\:mm:\:ss\;`

*You may adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*